# Ubuntu nvidia card seems not as efficient as windows.Everything is lagging

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, opengl

```
$ nvidia-smi

Sun Oct 21 13:39:10 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.87                 Driver Version: 390.87                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    568MiB /  4042MiB |      8%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      6097      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           215MiB |
|    0      6778      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         153MiB |
|    0      7427      G   ...-token=C0583651009EAB6ABD0003165A4446A0     9MiB |
|    0     14133      G   ...-token=BE20114554BDD89A25864C03852832D7   111MiB |
|    0     17782      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                      78MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ glxinfo | grep render

direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_NVX_nvenc_interop, 
    GL_NV_command_list, GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, 
    GL_NV_shader_thread_shuffle, GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_NVX_nvenc_interop, 
    GL_NV_command_list, GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, 
    GL_NV_shader_thread_shuffle, GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, 
    GL_EXT_multisample_compatibility, GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture, 
    GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2, GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean, 
    GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB, 
    GL_NV_clip_space_w_scaling, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_packed_float_linear, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, GL_NV_texture_array, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_geometry_point_size, 

$ prime-select query

nvidia
```

Firefox&Chromiun page scolling always lags.
Sometimes the pointer lags.
Window movement isn't smooth.

How to make ubuntu faster?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to KDE. That's much faster than GNOME shell.

```
sudo aptitude install kubuntu-desktop
```